# Regex to extract URI arguments such as URL's in webapp2 (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

In routes.py, I've tried below code (not a regex expert) and intend to pass http/https links in url_arg e.g. http://google.com or https://google.com.

```
r'/some_api/<url_arg:.*>'
```

Here is the error for localhost:8080/some_api/https://google.com or localhost:8080/some_api/http://google.com

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1292, in communicate
    req.parse_request()
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 580, in parse_request
    success = self.read_request_line()
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 643, in read_request_line
    scheme, authority, path = self.parse_request_uri(uri)
  File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 805, in parse_request_uri
    authority, path = remainder.split(FORWARD_SLASH, 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: The error means that ```remainder.split(...)``` only produced one item - so ```remainder``` must not have a ```FORWARD_SLASH``` in it.

Comment: That's right. What regex would work for WebApp2 though?

Comment: You may not have provided enough information search ```site:webapp2.readthedocs.io regex```... Seems like you would just need to ensure that your pattern matches the URL's you are looking for.  URL regex pattern matching is common and there are a lot of online resources/examples.  You can test your patterns at numerous on;line regex   testers/debuggers that use the Python flavor of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this is a bug in cherrypy, which app engine's devappserver2 uses. details: https://code.google.com/archive/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/69

(i have the same problem, and don't have a good fix or workaround yet.)